# Is there logging statements available for rake test in test-unit using ruby

Tags: ruby, rake, testunit

I am running rake test in ruby.

When I run rake test, I get the following output

```
rake TEST=test_cases/test.rb 

/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby -I"helpers" -I"/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@test/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib" "/home/karunakaran/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@test/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test_cases/test.rb" 
Loaded suite /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@test/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
.

Finished in 64.385604437 seconds.

1 tests, 16 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
100% passed

0.02 tests/s, 3.35 assertions/s
```

I want to get test suite logging at-least minimally instead just showing dot(.) for each test

Test logging like as below or any logging at step by step manner

```
Testname started
Running testname..
Error will display if we get any error
Testname completed
```

Comment: You probably want rake's `--format=doc` option.

Comment: @CodeGnome How to use --format=doc in rake. I haven't find that option in  rake -h
r